# Does increased rarity chance works on chests and similiar objects?

Tags: path-of-exile

Does the "increased rarity chance" you get from gear affects chests, large chest, boulders, and destroyable objects like pots, baskets, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it only applies to monsters slain. The mods on items are a bit misleading, it does not tell you that it only applies to slain mobs. The character screen states that it applies only to drops of mobs.

[source](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/51448/page/1#p654431), [source](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/58634/)